# Passar valor variável para input em outro arquivo PHP

Tags: php

Bom dia!

Tenho a seguinte situação:

Um cliente precisa preencher um formulário, e um dos campos deste formulário é para envio de imagens. Para se adaptar ao cliente, a janela para envio da imagem abre em um modal, em um arquivo diferente. O cliente escolhe a imagem, o upload é feito e o arquivo vai como md5.

Até aqui, tudo em paz.

Bem, o cliente é um usuário bem básico, mesmo para um "Ctrl C" e "Ctrl V", então preciso passar o nome do arquivo gerado (imagem) para o formulário anterior ao modal, no input.

Vou tentar demonstrar à partir de imagens:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na mesma página (modal) do upload, já dei um `echo` e recebo o nome da arquivo normalmente. O problema é que não estou conseguindo passar para o formulário anterior.

Será que consegui explicar? É algo simples, mas estou encontrando dificuldades.

Agradeço antecipadamente!

Comment: Já tentou colocá-lo em um input e via jQuery ou JavaScript pegar o valor e passar pro input da "tela" anterior? É bem simples de ser feito.

Comment: Bom dia, obrigado pela pronta resposta. Não o fiz, não sei como fazer. Se puder me dar uma referência para eu ler, agradeço!

Comment: Jquery não é meu forte, por isso preciso da referência.

Comment: Ok, mas tenho uma dúvida. Essa segunda página é um frame ou você tá recebendo o echo do PHP via AJAX?

Comment: É um frame, um arquivo php novo, um upload de imagens.

Comment: É, aí complicou um pouquinho kkk. Ainda dá pra fazer, mas preciso pensar. Vou tentar bolar algo aqui.

Comment: No modal do upload, já tinha colocado um `echo` para ver o nome do arquivo gerado, e tinha colocado dentro de um input. Só não sei como passar para o formulário anterior. Em PHP, desconheço!

Comment: Sim, com PHP puro você não vai conseguir. Tem que usar JavaScript. Já já eu volto com a resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Vamos lá.

Inclua o jQuery no seu projeto (é possível fazer  com JavaScript puro, é só pesquisar na internet).

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Inclua o código abaixo, ele irá chamar via AJAX a página responsável pelo envio das imagens quando algum dos botões for clicado.

```js
<script>
    function chamarUpload(btnId) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php', //Altere pelo arquivo de upload
            type: 'GET',
            data: 'btnId=' + btnId,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#divLightbox').html(data); //Altere para o ID do modal

                //Faça com que seu modal seja exibido
            },
            beforeSend: function() {
                //Se quiser, coloque uma animação, tipo loading...
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Altere o valor de url pro caminho do seu arquivo onde tem o form de upload, e dentro da function success, altere o divLightbox pro ID do seu "modal".

PS: se ao clicar no botão a página for atualizada, adicione `return false;` no final da function acima (antes da última chave).

PS²: Se você reparar no código, estamos fazendo uma solicitação `GET`, e estamos passando o parametro `btnId` com o valor btnId que recebemos ao chamar a function. Esse valor deve ser referente ao ID do seu `input` (cada input deve ter um ID diferente).

Sua página de upload, deve ter um código parecido com este

```html
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        //Faça tudo que for necessário pro upload da imagem
        //e conversão para MD5

        //Não esqueça de dar o echo.
        //O echo deve ser limpo, para exibir apenas o MD5, nada mais.

        //Não remova o exit.
        exit;
    }
?>
<div id="content-upload">
    <p>Somente arquivos JPEG, PNG e JPG são permitidos. O tamanho da imagem precisa ser menor que 5000KB</p>
    <hr>
    <form aciton="" method="post" id="form-upload">
        <input type="file" id="imagem" name="imagem">
        <button type="submit" id="btn-send">Enviar imagem</button>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#btn-send").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'upload.php', //chame essa mesma página
                type: 'POST',
                data: $('#form-upload').serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#<?= $_GET['btnId']; ?>").val(data);

                    //Nesse momento, o MD5 da imagem já deve ter sido atribuido
                    //ao campo, então feche o modal.
                },
                beforeSend: function() {
                    //Se quiser defina um loading pro upload
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Por fim, para chamar a página de upload e fazer ela ser incluída na div do seu modal, use o `href` dos links como: `javascript:chamarUpload(id do input que vai receber o md5);`

Ficando assim

```
<a href="javascript:chamarUpload('input1');" title="Fazer upload">Upload</a>
```

Ou, em outros elementos, use o onclick, ficando assim:

```
<img src="..." onclick="chamarUpload('input1');">
```

Comment: Ok, amigo. Vou mandar bala aqui e te retorno, caso tenha alguma dificuldade. Obrigado pelo seu tempo!

Comment: Não consigo carregar o conteúdo, o modal abre em branco... onde devo postar o código para mostrar?

Comment: Dá um inspecionar elemento (talvez só inspecionar) no navegador, e vai em console e vê se não tem nenhum erro lá. Acho que pode tirar uma print e postar o link aqui, ou editar sua pergunta e adicionar nela msm.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: chamarUpload is not defined(anonymous function) @ jquery-latest.min.js:3
(program):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: chamarUpload is not defined(anonymous function) @ jquery-latest.min.js:3

Comment: Valeu, erro encontrado... rs

Comment: Não sei como resolver... alguma dica?

Comment: Ele tá dizendo que a função chamarUpload não foi definida. Você alterou o nome da função? Digitou corretamente nos botões? Colocou a função chamarUpload e o jQuery na mesma página? O jQuery foi colocado antes da função?

Comment: Na msm página que eu falo, é na página onde estão os campos.

Comment: http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img922/5711/UjLSPA.jpg

Comment: Cadê o jQuery? Seu modal não usa um ID, portanto, lá na function, dentro do sucess, troque #venobox_custom por .venobox_custom ou adicione um id chamado venobox_custom ao modal. No parametro que você está passando pra chamar a função chamarUpload, você definiu btnId, pelo que vi o cerreto seria bancoimg1 que é o ID do input. Corrija isso, adicione o jQuery dentro da tag head do site e teste novamente.

Comment: Amigo, dê uma olhada no código do Modal. Parece tão simples, mas eu não estou enxergando o erro! http://imageshack.com/a/img921/9632/nzkzDB.jpg

Comment: Infelizmente, tive que ficar fora uns dias, problemas em família... mas enfim... estou tirando o venobox daqui e tentando criar uma janela modal com o próprio bootstrap, creio que esse venobox que está dando problemas aqui... assim que tiver novidades, volto para comentar.